# Hashing Results From C# and Java are Different

Tags: java, c#, hash, cryptography, sha

I'm trying to hash data "text" to be transferred from Java Service to C# Service.
I'm using SHA256 as a Hashing algorithm, but despite the values and the salt being the same the result doesn't.

Here is my C# snippet

```
public string Sign(string textToHash, string salt){
    byte[] convertedHash = new byte[salt.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length / 2; i++)
        convertedHash[i] = (byte)int.Parse(salt.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        
    HMAC hasher = new HMACSHA256(convertedHash);
       
    string hexHash = "";
    using (hasher)
    {
        byte[] hashValue = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToHash));
        foreach (byte b in hashValue)
        {
            hexHash += b.ToString("X2");
        }
    }
    return hexHash;
}
```

And, here is the Java snippet

```
public static String sign(String textToHash, String salt){
    
    byte[] convertedHash = new byte[salt.length() / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < salt.length() / 2; i++)
    {
        convertedHash[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(salt.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2),16);
    }
    String hashedText = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(convertedHash);
        byte[] bytes = md.digest(textToHash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aByte : bytes) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((aByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        hashedText = sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hashedText;
}
```

In Java, I also tried

```
convertedHash = salt.getBytes();
```

But I got different results also.

Tests:

```
salt = ABCDEFG
text = hashme
```

Result in C#

```
70B38047C28FFEDCF7275C428E65310671CADB65F11A5C9A8CFBB3CF52112BA3
```

Result in Java

```
a8bc36606aade01591a1d12c8b3c87aca1fe55def79740def03a90b49f2c6b7c
```

So, any help about why the results aren't the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In java snippet, What is "algorithm" in `        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);` ?

Comment: `System.out.printf("Default encoding. Java %s != C# %s%n", Arrays.toString("abc".getBytes()), Arrays.toString("abc".getBytes("UTF-16LE")));`

Comment: it is "SHA-256"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch
Alright, I got "Default encoding. Java [97, 98, 99] != C# [97, 0, 98, 0, 99, 0]",  but isn't UTF_8 are the same in C# and Java?

Comment: In questions like this it's better to provide sample input and outputs. Like "I try to hash string X with salt Y but in Java I get A as a result, and in C# I get B"

Comment: @Evk, thanks for the advice, I updated the question with the test cases and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mimic the Java hashing, I used `SHA256Managed` rather than `HMACSHA256` in C#

```
public static string Sign(string data, string salt)
{
    UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    SHA256Managed sha256hasher = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] convertedHash = new byte[salt.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length / 2; i++)
        convertedHash[i] = (byte)int.Parse(salt.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    byte[] dataBytes = encoder.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[convertedHash.Length + dataBytes.Length];
    
    Array.Copy(convertedHash, bytes, convertedHash.Length);
    Array.Copy(dataBytes, 0, bytes, convertedHash.Length, dataBytes.Length);
    byte[] hashedBytes = sha256hasher.ComputeHash(bytes);

    return hashedBytes.Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + t.ToString("X2"));
}
```

`HMACSHA256` is not a pure `SHA-256`.

Comment: Great, this is really a helpful answer, after I realized the difference between SHA256 with salt and SHA256 with HMAC "which is what I want as it is used for verifying integrity", I converted my java code to use the algorithm "HMACSHA256" instead of "SHA-256" with the same "hash to bytes" technique I do in C# and the results became the same. 
Thanks for your answer.